# How to decode and read a zstd file in Rust?

Tags: file, rust, io, zstd

I'm looking for some advice on how to decode and read a zstd file and I'm feeling a bit lost since it is my first big project since I started learning Rust.

I am using Rust for this project since it is for an internship and the data export/compression tool was written in Rust long ago so I thought I can take some inspiration. I am learning Rust from scratch so I am not very familiar with the structs and functions of the file i/o processes. I have a code snippet which is not working currently so I have some questions:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, BufReader};
use zstd::stream::read::Decoder;

fn read_lines<P>(filename: P) -> io::Result<io::Lines<io::BufReader<File>>>
where P: AsRef<Path>, { 
    if let Ok(file) = File::open(filename) { 
        if let Ok(buf_reader) = BufReader::new(file) { 
            if let Ok(decoder) = Decoder::new(buf_reader) { 
                return Ok(io::BufReader::new(decoder).lines()); } } } }

if let Ok(lines) = read_lines(filename) {

    for line in lines {
        if let Ok(ip) = line {
            println!("{}", ip)

        }
    }
}
```

Since it is a compressed file, should I decode it first as a whole and then start reading line by line? I know that the decompressed files are in jsonl format so each line is a separate json file. If the file size is too big to read it in one go, how should I proceed?

Also, if you have another package than zstd you are using that you would recommend, please share it with me. I would appreciate all the help.

Comment: *"should I decode it first as a whole and then start reading line by line?"* - is this really your question? Your next question implies definitely not, especially when what you've shown has (at least the idea of) a fully streamed solution (not reading all up-front). Though your types and syntax are quite a bit off, is that what the question is really about?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the thing is I couldn't really wrap my head around how it should work. I don't think it should decompress the file as a whole because I have been told that the files can get really big. But I also think that compression would not work line by line. The other thing is that I could not find many examples written in Rust where  big zstd files are decompressed so I wanted to ask here and get some ideas about how it should work.

Comment: @TrkDgnr You should not worry whether the decoder can actually decompress discrete whole lines, because that does not matter.  `BufReader` will wrap another reader and provide this capability. It does not buffer the whole file in memory, just enough to read ahead a little bit and see where a line ends, for example. So it will read just enough to get to a newline character, and maybe a little bit more than that.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I know this code is not correct syntaxwise, but do you think it is correct logicwise? First open the file, then put it into the buffer reader, then put it into the decoder of the zstd package, and parse it into lines. If so, I will try to keep the logic but try to make it work with the Rust syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going about it the right way, using the `Decoder` in a `BufReader` will allow you to read lines from the compressed file without requiring the whole file to be loaded up-front. The outer `BufReader` you use to read the lines will read chunks from the decoder until a newline is reached, and reading from the decoder will decode in chunks from the file.

You just haven't got the structure and return type correct. Here's what I would do:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader, Error as IoError, Lines};
use std::path::Path;

use zstd::stream::read::Decoder;

fn read_lines<P>(filename: P) -> Result<Lines<BufReader<Decoder<'static, BufReader<File>>>>, IoError>
where
    P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    let file = File::open(filename)?;
    let decoder = Decoder::new(file)?;
    Ok(BufReader::new(decoder).lines())
}
```

To explain a bit more:

- since `File::open` and `Decoder::new` both return `std::io::Error` if a problem is encountered, we can use `?` to return the error early and avoid nested `if-let`s.
- `Decoder::new` takes in a reader type and creates a `Decoder<'_, BufReader<_>>` (i.e. it creates a `BufReader` for the `File` itself) so we don't have to do that part.
- the return type has all the layers nested within eachother but if you like you can replace it with `Result<Lines<impl BufRead>, IoError>` in this instance to keep it concise.

Comment: Thank you for the replay and the code example! I tried running your function with a simple for loop in the main function and print each line to see if it is decoding, I got the error: Err(Custom { kind: Other, error: "Dictionary mismatch" }). Why do you think it gives a dictionary mismatch?

Comment: @TrkDgnr I'm not familiar with that error, but maybe [this](/q/60479799) and [this](/q/62304117) can help.

Comment: Ohh I see it, thank you for the links. I think the file I have is also compressed with an external dictionary but I don't have it currently. I will try to check with another file.